# What does the の's mean in this sentence of A to B comparison

Tags: grammar

1. The two の's, what are their functions here?
2. If I removed any or both of them how would that affect the sentence?
3. Does では mean **so then** here, or is「のではどちらが」a canned expression?

> 一人で旅する**<sup>(a)</sup>の**と友達と旅する**<sup>(b)</sup>の**ではどちらがいいですか？
>
> Which do you prefer? Traveling alone or traveling with your friends?

[Link to original tutorial/article](http://maggiesensei.com/2015/10/22/how-to-use-%E3%82%88%E3%82%8A-yori-comparative-form/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. の is being used as a nominalizer here. By placing の after an adjective or verb, you are able to create a dummy noun. Essentially, you are creating a noun phrase. For example:

> 新しいの 
> the new one.

> 新しいのが好き。
> I like the new one.

の here acts as a "dummy noun" that is being described by 新しい. In your case, this dummy noun is being modified by the verb 旅する.

> 一人で旅する = to travel alone (verb) 
> 一人で旅するの = travelling alone (noun phrase / gerund)

Likewise, 友達と旅するの is a noun phrase meaning "travelling with friends".

### XとY(と)では

Your second and third questions both fall into one answer. The first reason why you cannot remove の from this pattern is because と can only list nouns (の is what *allows* 旅する to become a noun). The second reason is because this is a set pattern.

As for this grammar pattern, it is one of the main ways to create a list from which 「どれ、どちら、どっち」 can choose from. では here essentially means "out of" or "between". If this does not sound clear, here is an example:

> 猫**と**犬**と**ウサギ（**と**）**では**どれが好き？ 
> Do you like cats, dogs, or rabbits the most? 
> More literal translation: Out of cats, dogs, and rabbits, which one do you like most?

Here is another example I stole from IMABI:

> ジョギングは、朝**と**夜**では**どっちがいいの 
> As for jogging, which is best, morning or night?

So for your example:

> 一人で旅するの**と**友達と旅するの（**と**）**では**どちらが いいですか？ 
> Literal Translation: Between travelling alone and travelling with friends, which one is better? 
> Natural translation: Do you prefer travelling alone or travelling with friends?

The addition of the second と makes it sound a bit more old fashioned. It is omitted often. In addition, と can be replaced with か when implying that you can choose from something outside of the list. You can find more information about this pattern [here](https://www.imabi.net/which.htm).

Comment: Great explanation, could you please clarify it the (と) is implied, optional, omitted or substituted by the では? Could you write AとBとでは…？

Comment: @JoelArt the final (と) is optional. AとBとでは is a completely valid way to use it.