# What is the difference among the three "と" in "私と旦那さんとの今の関係について話すとみんな驚いていました"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, particle-と

context:
...夜は飲みに行きました。みんなで近況を話して楽しかったです。私**と**旦那さん**と**の今の関係について話す**と**みんな驚いていました。

Do the first two "と" mean the same? If the first two "と" mean "and","I and my husband", why used two "と" here?

And what does the third "と" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first and second と are listing particles. The second と is optional. As for why と is sometime used twice, see: [Question about the と particle in comparative constructs](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/83411/5010)

The third と is a conjunctive meaning "when" or "and (then)". See: [Differences among -たら, なら, -と, -んだったら, -ば, etc](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/393/5010)